# How to solve $\min_x || x ||_1$, such that $Ax=b$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I'm not very familiar with optimization problems, so I'm looking for references on how to solve problems like
$$ \min_x ||x||_1, \text{ such that }  \text{A}x = b.$$
In my example, $x$ is an image, and A can be a linear transformation, such as the Radon transform.

I know that I can form the Lagrangian
$$ L(x, \lambda) = ||x||_1 + \lambda (\text{A} x - b),$$
which then leads to algorithms involving the step
$$ x_{k+1} = \arg\min_x L(x,\lambda_k). $$
Here I get stuck, as I don't know how to solve/implement this step.

I'm thankful for any hint on literature or examples on how to implement this.

Comment: It is a linear problem, you could use an LP solver also.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I'm rather looking for maybe a Pseudocode example on how to implement it myself for this specific example.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_i = z_i^+ - z_i^-$  and $|x_i|=z_i^+ + z_i^-$ where $z_i^+, z_i^- \ge 0$.

Hence we can write the problem as

$$\min \sum_{i=1}^n (z_i^++z_i^-) $$

subject to $z_i^+, z_i^- \ge 0$ and $A(z^+-z^-)=b$.

This is a linear programming problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I'm looking for something like a Pseudocode example, to implement this algorithm/minimization myself, without using any predefined functions (e.g. Matalbs linprog). Do you have any resources on that?